# Convexity of $f(W)=\Vert W^TW - I\Vert_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis

Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$, where $k\leq d$. Moreover, let $\Vert\cdot\Vert_F$ denote the Frobenius norm. Assume also that the function $f(W)$ is defined as:
$$f(W)=\Vert W^TW - I\Vert_F,$$
where $T$ is the transpose operator and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Is the function $f$ convex in terms of $W$?

Comment: Obviously not. Let $W$ be a matrix with orthonormal columns. Then $\frac{f(W)+f(-W)}{2}=0<\|I_k\|_F=f(0)=f(\frac{W+(-W)}{2})$.